# Disabling on-the-fly projecting in Arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.4

Using Arcmap 10.4.1 I'd like to temporarily disable on-the-fly projecting, so as to be able to visually see the spatial offset between two vector layers with differing CRS and/or transformations. A search through the Arc help system, as well as an internet search, turns up nothing.

QGIS has a checkbox that can turn on/off on-the-fly projecting (which works great!), and I'm hoping for something similar in Arc.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. This solution didn't work for me. ArcMap still automatically transformed the data to align the two data sets - one in nad27 and the other in nad83. I somehow got this to work once in ArcMap but cannot repeat it. I've cleared the display cache but can't repeat. It's just taking a set of lat long coordinates. Display XY coordinates and then save the shapefile of points without any projection information. Make a copy. In copy 1, project define as NAD 27. In copy 2 project define as NAD 83.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not particularly obvious but it can be done per data frame:

- Open your data frame properties;
- Click the coordinate system tab;
- Click the dropdown next to the coordinate system (globe) button;
- Click "Clear".

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @Luke.  When do I apply your solution: 1) Before any layers are added, or 2) after the first layer has been added, or 3) after all layers have been added?  Thanks!

Comment: My testing shows that option #3 is correct, but I wanted to confirm with you.

Comment: Yep #3 as ArcMap will (I think but can't test) change the data frame coordinate system when you add data.

Comment: I can confirm... @Luke's solution needs to be applied after all layers have been added.