# Satellite image projection

Tags: coordinate-system, modis, hdf, aster

I am comparing ASTER and MODIS LST images. For this I converted the images from HDF format to GeoTIFF format using ERDAS 2013 of my study area.  MODIS image is reprojected to the same projection of aster image and the shape file of the study area also. But the two satellite images does not overlap with the shape file. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide details on your processing procedure. It is likely to did not preproject correctly and therefore corrupted your dataset, so the solution is to start over where things went wrong.

Comment: I have done this using different datasets. For example I downloaded MODIS LST image and ASTER LST image for Algeria  and the shape file for Algeria also. The satellite images are converted from HDF format to GeoTIFF format using ERDAS 2013 and the three of them are projected to WGS 84 UTM 31 N in ArcMap 10.3. But the images did not overlap with the shape file.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/271811/8104